# Black-Scholes delta of a barrier (knock-out or knock-in) option

Tags: black-scholes, delta, barrier

I'm trying to calculate the Black-Scholes delta of a barrier option given the following information:

1. Whether it is knock-out or knock-in
2. Barrier price
3. Strike price, $X$
4. Current stock price, $S$
5. Number of days to expiry, $\tau$
6. Whether it is a call or a put
7. Implied volatility, $\sigma$
8. Risk-free rate, $r$
9. Note: there is 0 dividend yield

I know the formula for the delta of a basic call option is the following:
$$N(d_1)\text{ where}$$
$$d_1 = \frac{ln(S/X)+(r+\sigma^2/2)\tau}{\sigma\sqrt{\tau}}$$

Is there a similar formula for a barrier option?